# Make starred comments box in chat scrollable

Tags: feature-request, chat, user-interface, design, chat-stars

[image: hints of text above the red line]

Just above the red hand-drawn line, it should be obvious there are crests of some text lettering peeking through. Can we just have the box in a scrollable DIV?