# Chat starwall is cropped

Tags: bug, chat, design, user-interface, chat-stars

Chat rooms don't show all the messages of star wall, if chatroom is opened from a low-resolution and/or small screen.

For example, below is the screenshot taken from my Macbook pro, 13 inch screen at resolution 1280x800, from chrome:

[image]

<sub>Freehand circle, courtesy of [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard)</sub>

The bug persists irrespective of browser. I have also tried it on various 15 inch screens with same resolution (1200x720) on Windows OS and Linux.

The starwall doesn't scroll down either, like the rest of chat, so I am not able to see the messages that are hidden below.

Comment: I thought you would never use Windows <3

Comment: lol, I had to check it @TheLittleNaruto, though hate levels are still at highest ;)

Comment: So much hatred in this world. ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: btw +1 because that non-scrollable star wall is annoying.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto wrong place to use lenny emoji, guess still long way to go for you...

Comment: @berserk ;-; ;-;

Comment: @DroidDev Maybe chatrooms just wanna be friends...

Comment: or maybe its just the starwall @berserk

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156178/make-starred-comments-box-in-chat-scrollable